# imaginary error function in c++

Tags: c++, math

Is there a GPL library or a piece of code freely available that implements the imaginary error function:

```
erfi(x)=-i*erf(i*x)
```

where `x` is any complex number (or at least real) and `i` is the imaginary unit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A free/open-source C++ implementation of all of the usual error functions for real and complex arguments, including both erfi and a scaled erfi (to cancel erfi's exponential growth) (the Dawson function), including optimizations for erfi of real arguments, is available at http://ab-initio.mit.edu/Faddeeva

(Note that this implementation is actually used in the upcoming version 0.12 of SciPy, replacing the complex-erf code in earlier versions which had accuracy problems: http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1207)

(Unfortunately, evaluating special functions of complex arguments isn't as simple as plugging complex numbers into code for real arguments, which is why the templating in Boost's real-valued erf is of no help here.)

Comment: I checked Steven's code using a Fourier transform method, and I can confirm that it is accurate to at least 13 digits, typically 14-15 digits. I wrapped Steven's code as a C library, [libcerf](http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/libcerf), complete with man pages and autotools installation scripts.

Answer (score 3):

After finding that Boost doesn't support complex numbers for the erf function, I did some more searching. I found several $100 per year math packages for C++, which doesn't meet your needs. So then I looked in other languages and found that the SciPy package in Python does support complex numbers in it's erf function.

```
>>> from scipy.special import erf
>>> from numpy import complex
>>> erfi = lambda z: complex(0.0, -1.0)*erf(complex(0.0, 1.0)*z)
>>> z_in = complex(0.75, 1.25)
>>> erfi(z_in)
(0.09511238... + 1.0828473...j)
```

Which matches erfi(0.75+1.25*i) from wolphramalpha exactly.

Thus to use this in C++ you can integrate this through Boost.Python, Cython, or a variety of other packages. See [embedding Python in C++](http://wangqiang8511.com/2012/07/18/embedding-python-in-c-application/) for some code examples of wrapping Python in C++. Note that this does add a requirement to have Python and SciPy installed on your system, but I didn't see many implementations that weren't subscription based and took complex arguments, so you might be restricted to other language packages without implementing it yourself.

**!EDIT** Answer below shown to not extend to complex numbers **EDIT!**

If you're using C++ then try looking into Boost's math library (erf is defined [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_erf/error_function.html) and boost supports complex numbers so you should be able to use it directly with complex values to perform the right-hand side of erfi's calculation: i*erf(i*x).

Comment: [erf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/erf) is also included in C++11 in cmath.

Comment: @Jesse Yes, but C++11 cmath's erf doesn't handle complex numbers -- only real

Comment: @DavidHammen It's templated, so unless it's implemented in a strange way -- As long as the power function is defined for the complex number going in, then it should be compilable. I can test it specifically later to confirm, but there's nothing in the documentation sayings its specific to integer types, just that it returns an integer type if T is another integer type.

Comment: compiling boost::math::erf(std::complex(0,1)) does not work! At least when I try it...

Comment: @Pyrce: Yes, it's templated, but it only works for real floating point numbers: `float`, `double`, 80 bit `long double`, 128 bit `long double`. The implementation uses typical numerical approximation techniques. It breaks the real number line into a bunch of intervals and uses predetermined, interval-specific polynomials to approximate erf(x). The algorithm can't be used with complex numbers because complex numbers don't compare less than (i.e., there is no `operator <` for complex numbers).

Comment: @DavidHammen Yup you're right, I tried a few test examples today and updated my answer. It's too bad they didn't implement erf in Boost with complex values in mind, or just add erfi to the library.

Answer (score 1):

For real values of `x`, you can use the GNU Scientific Library (GSL), which implements the [Dawson function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.html#dawson-function). Multiply the value of this function by 2π<sup>-1/2</sup>exp(*x*<sup>2</sup>), and you get erfi(*x*).